# What's the best way to handle JSON API responses using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm working on a project that communicates with an API using JSON.  This is my first attempt at JSON and I've been away from java for a few/several years, so please bear with me.

Here is an idea of what the data looks like:

String 1:

```
[{
  "apicall1": 
     [{
      "thisField":"thisFieldData",
      "thatField":"thatFieldData",
      "anotherField":"anotherFieldData"
     }]
}]
```

String 2:

```
[{
  "apicall2":
     [{
      "thatField":"thatFieldData",
      "someFieldsAreTheSame":"someFieldsAreTheSameData",
      "otherFieldsAreNotTheSame":"otherFieldsAreNotTheSame"
     }]
}]
```

As you can see from my data example, the API returns a JSON string that contains the api used.  The array inside contains the data.  The API's have a lot of data fields in common but they are unrelated beyond that.

**EDIT: There are dozens of these API's types that will need to be handled.**

What I am trying to do is create a response class that accepts all of the JSON strings and returns an object containing the appropriate data.

For Example:

```java
Gson gson = new Gson(); //Custom TypeAdapter goes here if needed.
Response apicall2 = gson.fromJson(apicall2String, Response.class);

System.out.println(apicall2.thatField);                //Prints thatFieldData 
System.out.println(apicall2.someFieldsAreTheSame);     //Prints someFieldsAreTheSameData
System.out.println(apicall2.otherFieldsAreNotTheSame); //Prints otherFieldsAreNotTheSameData
```

This is where I am lost.  Here is what I have so far. I think I need to use a TypeAdapter here but haven't been able to figure how to apply that to my case.

```java
 public class Response {  //Change to TypeAdapter possibly?
 }
 public class apicall1 {
      String thisField;
      String thatField;
      String anotherField;
 }
 public class apicall2 {
      String thatField;
      String someFieldsAreTheSame;
      String otherFieldsAreNotTheSame;
 }
```

Comment: You could use this site to make your Java classes from your JSON. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: It's not so much the making of the classes that's the issue.  It's finding the best way to manage the transition from the JSON to those classes and back.  Interesting site none the less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gson's `TypeToken` class to deserialize json into object. Below is an example:

**JSON:**

```
[{  "apicall1": 
     [{
      "thisField":"thisFieldData",
      "thatField":"thatFieldData",
      "anotherField":"anotherFieldData"
     }]
}]
```

**Model:**

```
class Response{

    private List<Result> apicall1;

    class Result{
        private String thisField;
        private String thatField;
        private String anotherField;
        public String getThisField() {
            return thisField;
        }
        public void setThisField(String thisField) {
            this.thisField = thisField;
        }
        public String getThatField() {
            return thatField;
        }
        public void setThatField(String thatField) {
            this.thatField = thatField;
        }
        public String getAnotherField() {
            return anotherField;
        }
        public void setAnotherField(String anotherField) {
            this.anotherField = anotherField;
        }
    }

    public List<Result> getApicall1() {
        return apicall1;
    }

    public void setApicall1(List<Result> apicall1) {
        this.apicall1 = apicall1;
    }
}
```

**Converter:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String response = "[{  \"apicall1\":      [{      \"thisField\":\"thisFieldData\",      \"thatField\":\"thatFieldData\",      \"anotherField\":\"anotherFieldData\"     }]}]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Response> responses = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<Response>>(){}.getType());
    System.out.println(responses.get(0).getApicall1().get(0).getThisField());
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to wrap my head around your answer, but I think you may be onto something with the TypeToken. Is this the same concept as a TypeAdapterFactory?

Comment: Yes, it's similar concept. TypeToken allows you to pass generic types as class types.

Comment: After chewing over this for a while, I think I am better off moving toward the TypeAdapterFactory.  Your solution works with my example, but I'm going to box myself in as the project grows if all of the classes are nested inside of the response class.

Comment: Classed needn't be nested. I used it just to provide an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), classes can be present in any package. Anyway, whether to go with this or TypeAdapterFactory is your call.

Comment: True enough.  I'm going to have to try both methods, I think, to see which works better in practice. I certainly like your approach better, if I can pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want both adapters in one class. Might not be the best OOP design.

To achieve it you would need to do something like so:

```
public class DoublyTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<ApiCallTypeParent>
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public ApiCallTypeParent deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext)
            throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject json = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

        ApiCallTypeParent desrializeIntoMe;
        // Detect which type to implement
        if(apiTypeOne(type) {
              desrializeIntoMe = new TypeOne();
        } else {
              desrializeIntoMe = new TypeTwo();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : json.entrySet())
        {
            switch(entry.getKey()){
            case "thisField":
                desrializeIntoMe.setThisField(entry.getValue().getAsString());
                break;
            ......    
            default: // We don't care
                break;
            }
        }

        return desrializeIntoMe ;
      }
}
```

Comment: "Might not be the best OOP design."  You're probably correct.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post that I will be dealing with dozens of API's (edit coming).  I'm not sure a string of if statements is the best approach either.

Comment: Certainly. Much bigger fan of the other answer.